# Does Gaudiya Vaishnava believe that Lakshmi mata left Sri Narayana bhagvan for Lord Krishna ji?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vaishnavism, lakshmi, rukmini

That Krishna and Vishnu are closely related but two different gods is a well known philosophy within Krishna centric sects like Gaudiya or Nimbarkas. So in them Krishna is more beautiful and important than Vishnu in the order of precedence

In one of the story I was told that Lakshmi mata, the wife of Narayana bhagvan was so enamoured of Krishna ji that she was desperate to be Krishna's wife as Rukmini, as Krishna has himself incarnated on Earth in the present dwapar yuga.

Is this story supported by any prominent scriptures?

Comment: This would be a disturbing question to Hindus who don't follow Gaudiya theology.